# USB Token for autentication in website form

Tags: html, authentication, usb, token

I have a website with HTML login form I want to use USB device as token to login into my website.

How can I use USB device for authentication and login via USB flash memory.

Is it possible to copy something like certificate on USB and when I connect it to my computer its automatically log into Website.

Thank you

Comment: For PKI Web login, you may use free Signer.Digital Browser Extensions from modern browsers. Refer this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the yubikey, a good and inexpensive usb-token (http://www.yubico.com/yubikey).

Yubikeys register als usb keyboard, and because of that work on every system (that support usb keyboards) without the installation of any device drivers.

You can find many examples online how to use their one-time-key authentification service with php, ruby-on-rails or whatever language you use for your webpage.

If your system isn't connected to the internet you can still use the static key that the yubikey also can generate.

Comment: In addition, you can also download the [open-source server](http://www.yubico.com/validation-server) from their site and use authenticate the OTPs on you own hardware without internet-connection.

Comment: I found an extension to devise gem - https://github.com/CyberDeck/devise-fido-u2f